# simpy Requests piling up in queue

Tags: python, resources, simulation, simpy

I am simulating meetings in conference rooms and I started with the Bank Renege example as a model.
It is working as intended - this first version just tries to put 5 meetings into 3 rooms in several different hours.
HOWEVER, I notice that the queued requests (those who don't get a conference room) accumulate in the Resource.queue  list. Shouldn't they release and disappear? Is this an error on my part? I have tried
req.cancel
simpy.Interrupt
and a few other attempts, to no effect that I can tell.

```
RANDOM_SEED = 181106
NbrMtgs = 5  # Total number of meetings in a period
INTERVAL = 1.0  # Generate new meetings every x hours

def Schedule(env, NbrMtgs, interval, ResRooms):
    #Source generates meetings
    while True:
        for i in range(NbrMtgs):
            h=env.now
            m = Meet(env, 'Meeting%02d_%02d' % (h,i), ResRooms, TimeInMtg=MtgLen)
            env.process(m)
        t = 1
        yield env.timeout(t)

def Meet(env, name, ResRooms, TimeInMtg):
    #Customer arrives, is served and leaves.
    arrive = env.now
    print('%7.4f %s: Here I am' % (arrive, name))

    with ResRooms.request() as req:
        results = yield req | env.timeout(MtgLen)

        wait = env.now - arrive

        if req in results:
            # We got to the ResRooms
            print('%7.4f %s: Waited %6.3f' % (env.now, name, wait))

            #tib = random.expovariate(1.0 / TimeInMtg)
            yield env.timeout(TimeInMtg)
            print('%7.4f %s: Finished' % (env.now, name))

        else:
            # We reneged
            #req.cancel() this doesnt clear queue and does give an error at last step
            # no notable effect  ResRooms.release(req)
            #simpy.Interrupt('No rooms')  still piling up. no effect
            #yield env.timeout(TimeInMtg)
            print('%7.4f %s: RENEGED after %6.3f' % (env.now, name, wait))
        print("this req=",req)  # is something like   <Request() object at 0x2449892f908>
        print("users",ResRooms.users)
        print("queue",ResRooms.queue)

env = simpy.Environment()

# Start processes and run
ResRooms = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=3)
MtgLen = 1
Hours = 8


env.process(Schedule(env, NbrMtgs, INTERVAL, ResRooms))
env.run(until=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

No that's not an error. If you request the resources the way you did, with the with-statement, all the request that did not get the resource will end up in the queue and wait until the resource is available again. Do you want to cancel those requests?